# On some notations and notions of a paper on smoothness of Schubert varieties by Lakshmibai and Sandhya

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, flag-varieties, schubert-varieties

I am reading the paper Criterion for smoothness of Schubert varieties in $\mathrm{Sl}(n)/B$ by V Lakshmibai and B Sandhya; Proc. Indian Acad. Sci. (Math. Sci.), Vol. 100, No. 1, April 1990, pp. 45-52.  https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/pmsc/100/01/0045-0052.

There are a few notions and notations in the paper that I don't understand. My questions are :

(1) In page 3 of the paper (printed page 47), in Section 2, the authors define certain parabolic subgroups $Q_i$ inductively as $Q_1=P_1$ and $Q_{i+1}=Q_i \cap P_{i+1}$ . What I don't understand is: What are these $P_i$ s ?

(2) In Theorem 2.1, they use the notion of "equidimensionality" of the restriction of  projection maps. What does this being equidimensional mean ?

(3) In Theorem 2.1, what does $W(Q_i)$ mean ? Is it the Weyl subgroup corresponding to $Q$ i.e. is $W(Q_i) \cong N_{Q_i} (T)/T$ ?

It would be highly appreciated if someone could clarify my doubts. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest that you rephrase your title. As it stands, it sounds like you doubt that the paper is correct...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: does it look okay now ?

Comment: Yes, it's much better.

Comment: I would guess that the P_i’s are maximal parabolics.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi In some versions of the English language (notably in India), "doubt" just means "question".

Comment: @SamHopkins: In that case like $P_i$ s are maximal parabolics whose intersection is $B$ right ? Some question is this regard: Is such an intersection unique (modulo of course the order in which the subgroups may appear) ?  Does maximal mean w.r.t. set inclusion here ? And does $Sl(n,\mathbb C)$ contain only $n$-many maximal parabolics ?

Comment: I think they’re the “standard” maximal parabolics corresponding to the nodes of the Dynkin diagram.

Comment: @SamHopkins: I think you're right ... $P_i$ s should just be the subgroup of all matrices in $Sl(n)$ whose $i$-th column is $\lambda e_i$ for some non-zero $\lambda$ ...

Comment: @AndreasBlass I don't doubt it :)

Comment: The survey paper [Lakshmibai, Musili, and Shesadri - Geometry of $G/P$](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1979-01-02/S0273-0979-1979-14631-7) is more careful.  It says:  (1) $P_i$ is the maximal parabolic corresponding to the fundamental weight $\pi_i$ (p. 433); (2) $W_Q = N_Q(T)/T$ (p. 432), as you guess.  It does not mention equi-dimensionality, but an algebraic-geometer colleague says that the unusual useage probably suggests that there is some $d$ such that every component of every fibre has dimension $d$.

Comment: @LSpice: thanks ... when you say every component of every fibre, do you mean every "irreducible component " ? And by fibre here, do you mean just pre-images of points or fibre in the Scheme theoretic Algebraic-Geometric sense ?

Comment: @LSpice: Also, in our case, does $P_i$ turn out to be just the subgroup of all matrices in $Sl(n)$ whose $i$-th column is $\lambda e_i$ for some non-zero $\lambda$ ?

Comment: I think that $P_i$ should be the block upper-triangular matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix} A & X \\ 0 & B \end{pmatrix}$, where $A$ is $i \times i$ and $B$ is $(n - i) \times (n - i)$.

Comment: @LSpice: Okay, will try to verify it, thanks a lot ... if possible, could you also answer my concerns I raised about the component of fibre in the other comment ?

Comment: Yes, by 'component' I mean 'irreducible component'.  As to 'fibre', I'm not sure, but I think that the Schubert-cell decomposition into $B$-homogeneous spaces means that there is only one reasonable notion here—namely, the spaces $\tau P_1/B \cap X(w)$ with $\tau \le w$, and their left $B$-translates.  The proof given in the text seems to be showing that this fibre, considered as a stand-alone variety, is equi-dimensional for $\tau = 1$; maybe some general AG nonsense will show that that is enough.

Comment: Most journals seem to have a stable landing page for their articles, but PMSIAS seems to want you to link only to the PDF page (or, at least, that's the target of what they give as the permanent link).  Nonetheless, there is a page for the abstract:  https://www.ias.ac.in/describe/article/pmsc/100/01/0045-0052.

Comment: Lakshmibai has many books. Maybe the notation is in his book with Billey or in his book with Brown.

Answer (score 1):

(3) My guess would be that $W(Q_i)$ is the Weyl group of the Levi part of $Q_i$.

(2) My guess would be that it means that the domain and codomain have the same dimension.

(1) I have no guess.

Bottom line: This is bad writing.

Comment: thanks for your view ... it might be bad writing, but every single paper or monograph on smoothness or singular loci of Schubert varieties that I've seen, does refer to this paper, and I'm really trying to understand this paper :-(

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator\Int{Int}$Note that there is no difference between the Weyl group of a parabolic $Q$, in the sense proposed by @user102248, and the Weyl group of a Levi component.  Indeed if $Q = M U$ is a Levi decomposition, and if $m \in M$ and $u \in U$ are such that $m u$ normalises $T$, then the image of $\Int(m u)T = T$ in $Q \to Q/U$ is $\Int(m)T = T$, so $m \in N_M(T)$; so then $u \in N_U(T)$, but, if $u \ne 1$, then there is some $t \in T$ that doesn't centralise $u$, so $\Int(u)t^{-1} = t^{-1}\cdot[t, u] \in T$ has non-trivial component $[t, u] \in U$, which is a contradiction.